# Raising a minibox fails in a non-p tabular cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

While trying to answer a `tabular` related question here I found the following behavior which surprised me:

I'm trying to overlap a multi-line text in an otherwise left aligned column
with the empty cell above. This is intended as an alternative to the `multirow` package in this case. 
I tried `\raisebox{<amount>}[0pt]{\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>} .. \end{minipage}}` (or `\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t]{<width>},raise={<amount>}{0pt}`) but this does not raise the `minipage` at all when a `l`, `c` or `r` column type is used. It works for `p{<width>}`.

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{6cm}}
    text & .\raisebox{1ex}{Text} \\
    text &
    .\raisebox{2\baselineskip}{\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}% baseline is raised
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}} \\
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\begin{tabular}{ll}% same for c and r
    text & .\raisebox{1ex}{Text} \\
    text &
    .\raisebox{2\baselineskip}{\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}% baseline is not raised!
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result with 'p' type:

[image: With 'p' type]

Result with 'l' type:

[image: With 'l' type]

This behavior escapes me. It is usually always possible to use a `minipage` in an otherwise horizontal mode. I guess that maybe some internal macro is redefined which interferes with this? Can anyone explain why this happens and how to make `\raisebox` work also for non-`p` column types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is too complicated. The problem is that you are using `\baselineskip` that's set to zero in l-columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}% same for c and r
    text & .\raisebox{1ex}{Text} \\
    text &
    .\the\baselineskip. \raisebox{\baselineskip}{blub}\raisebox{1cm}{BLA}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And `\normalbaselineskip` can be used in place of `\baselineskip`

Comment: Thanks Ulrike and @egreg. I knew it must be some macro redefinition, but would not have guessed `\baselineskip` to be the cause. You are right Ulrike, I should have used a direct value instead.